# how to calculate the bounding box of an arc?

Tags: algorithm, polygon

I have an arc with three known points B(Xb,Yb), C(Xc,Yc), and D(Xd,Yd).B and C are the two endpoints of the arc, and D is a random control point on the arc. Now I need to get the minimum bounding box of this arc.

Please ignore the coordinates and grid points in the chart，arcs may be of any shape.

I am currently writing a C++ geometry library about arc polygons. Obtaining the bounding box of arc polygons is a relatively basic part of it. However, I have little experience in geometry and I was stumped in the first step.
Is there any good calculation method?
Thanks for your discussion and help.

[image: Arc bounding box]

Comment: Why are they "inapplicable" or "inefficient"? Did you try anything?

Comment: Edit the question with what you are reffering to when you say `AABB`, `OBB` and `MBR`. For what I found, these are not algorithms to find minimum bounding box. Also, explain what woule be efficient enough for you.

Comment: What do you know about points B, C and D? From the figure it's clear that if B (xB, yB) and C (xC, yC) and the radius is r, then the bounding-box is given by F (xB, r) and G(-r, yC). Note that this is true because of the dispositions of points B and C and might be false if they were in other quadrants.

Comment: From the figure, it looks like B = (3, 1), which means the radius of the circle is r = sqrt(10) (to calculate the radius, use Pythagoras' theorem on triangle AJB where J(3, 0) is the point on the x-axis below B), so the coordinates of point F would be (3, sqrt(10)), but I can't say anything about yC just by looking at this figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms AABB (axis aligned bounding box), OBB (oriented bounding box) and MBR (minimum bounding rectangle = 2D bounding box), are not algorithms for finding bounding boxes, they are types of bounding boxes.

Assuming that you are looking for an axis aligned box for an arc starting at point A, going through a point M and ending at point B, you can do the following steps which do not require any trigonometric functions:

- use the coordinates of A,M,B to find the center `C=[Cx,Cy]` and radius `r` of the circle through points A,M,B using this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1460096) and define the points

  `E=[Cx+r,Cy]`

  `N=[Cx,Cy+r]`

  `W=[Cx-r,Cy]`

  `S=[Cx,Cy-r]`
- calculate the areas of the triangles ABM, ABE, ABN, ABW, ABS:

  `ABM = (Ax*(By-My) + Bx*(My-Ay) + Mx*(Ay - By))/2`

  `ABE = (Ax*(By-Ey) + Bx*(Ey-Ay) + Ex*(Ay - By))/2`

  `...`
- if `ABM*ABE > 0` then `BBxmax = Ex` else `BBxmax = max(Ax,Bx)`
- if `ABM*ABN > 0` then `BBymax = Ny` else `BBymax = max(Ay,By)`
- if `ABM*ABW > 0` then `BBxmin = Wx` else `BBxmin = min(Ax,Bx)`
- if `ABM*ABS > 0` then `BBymin = Sy` else `BBymin = min(Ay,By)`

After these steps, `[BBxmin,BBymin]` and `[BBxmax,BBymax]` should be the corners of the minimum axis aligned bounding box you are interested in.

Comment: Isn't `ABM*ABE` always bigger than 0 ? (expect on a few trivial cases). Did you mean `ABM - ABE` ?

Comment: Regarding the ABM*ABE > 0 part, I am also a little confused and do not understand it well.

Comment: The formula for calculating area ABX is such that it gives a positive value if X is on one side of the line AB, while it gives a negative value if X is on the other side of AB. In the check ABM * ABE > 0 we are not interested in the size of the two areas but on their sign. If both have the same sign, then points M and E are on the same side of the line AB.

Comment: @Konstantinos Oh, now i get it. Pretty smart indeed.